# Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I dont know what is going on with this "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.". Do you guys know what happened? My wcf service was running fine, but today I got this error. I searched on google but no answers could be found.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm getting the same message. I get the message whenever I try to add an EDMX or DBML file and "The operation could not be completed. Unspecified error" on successive attempt to open the file (it creates it fine and even runs, it just won't open it the the designer.)

Comment: If you're still having this problem, then please post the full exception. Catch the exception, then post the results of `ex.ToString()`

Comment: @John Saunders: I have similar error showing up randomly as well. Could you please have a look at my question @ `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259801/system-reflection-targetinvocationexception` and provide any feedback? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Voodoo: that's not how it works here. You posted your question, and people with the knowledge to answer it will answer it.

Comment: @John Saunders: ok thanks. The only reason to ask you was that you seemed to be pretty knowledgeable, so I thought what the hey! I didn't mean to break any SO rules here.

Comment: @Voodoo: "we learn by doing". Doing the wrong thing, that is, and being shown where we're wrong.

Comment: Can you please show the stack trace so we know more specifically what you are doing?

Answer (score 3):

E_FAIL is a generic unknown error.  There is no more specific information.

Rather than searching for E_FAIL, I'd search for support more specific to some of the COM components you are using, specifically which one actually returned this error if you can find it out.

Answer (score 0):

These are generic vs controls, anything/everything in my page is giving the same error. Even with a brand new site created in vs

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to this:
[Some sharepoint-blog](http://sriramkunapuli.com/2012/04/30/sharepoint-search-cant-crawl-sharepoint-site-error-hresult-e_fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component/)

That is  - change to

```
    <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <identity impersonate="true" />
        </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

in web.config might work. Inverstigate the other possible consequences of this though.