# How to test app license via mobile emulator in UWP?

Tags: uwp

In Visual Studio 2015, via debugger, I use code

```
var purchaseStatus = await CurrentAppSimulator.RequestAppPurchaseAsync(false)
```

to test App. licence in UWP app. It works well with local machine and simulator, but with mobile emulator 10.0.10240.0, the call throws `COMException` with message:

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Should the call to test license be the same to all devices in UWP app?  If mobile device is diff, what should it be?

Answer (score 0):

E_FAIL is a generic unknown error. There is no more specific information.

Your question has been asked before, but nobody has given any deterministic answers , you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822766/error-hresult-e-fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component) . I have test your code and found the same error.

Comment: Thanks John.  Any comment on that as UWP, should the testing code for license be the same for all devices, include mobile?  BTW, the code works on my Surface.

Comment: I  have tested on mobile and PC , it works well on PC but error on mobile